# Image-link to content works only on preview

Tags: views, media

I have a view showing content of a specific content type. In the view, I show 2 links, linking back to the specific content. The first one is an image field and the second is the title field. Both links work on the preview but on the actual display only the title links to the content. The view is shown through a panel.

Comment: Your question not understandable- explain it clearly and are you using views to show the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views preview does not use templates from your theme. Expand Advanced on the right, and in Other section click Theme: Information. Find .tpl.php files that are bolded and may apply to your fields (are applied to them directly, or to their parents). Look for them in your theme's directory and search them for errors.

If that will not help, offending template comes from Panels, not Views themselves.

Comment: One of the templates was overwriting the default html. I just enclosed the HTML output with l() and it worked! Thanks Molot